# Global Variable is not being assigned outside function.

Tags: javascript, scope

I am attempting to set a global variable using Javascript. I know that the scope is correct and the value is retained as long as the page is not closed. Even on a refresh it should retain its value. It is not.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    noproductfound=0;
    noamount=0;
    nodept=0;


    function loadpage(){
        statusset="";
                    if(noproductfound==1){
                        alert('NO PRODUCT FOUND IN DATABASE. ENTER AMOUNT AND DEPARTMENT.');

                    }
                    else if(noamount==1){
                        alert('NO AMOUNT ENTERED. PLEASE ENTER AMOUNT AND DEPARTMENT');
                        //document.getElementById('current_amount').focus();
                    }
                    else if(nodept==1){
                        alert('NO DEPARTMENT ENTERED. PLEASE ENTER');

                    }
                    else if(statusset==1) {
                        alert('Global statusset is set');
                    }

                    else{
                    alert('NO GLOBALS HAVE BEEN SET');
                    }
    }

    function checkthis(){
        window.statusset=1;
        location.reload();
    }

    </script>
        <title>Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadpage()">
    <button  onclick="checkthis()" type="submit">Set GLOBAL Status</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Any state represented only in JavaScript doesn't survive beyond an unload / reload of the page. You'll need to use a layer of persistence, such as [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie), [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage), etc. to retain the value.

Comment: `Even on a refresh it should retain its value` ... definitely not so

Comment: It will not retain its value on refresh. On refresh, the script will run all over again.

Comment: No global variables persist because it is bind with windows and onload DOM will regenerate it.

Comment: Jonathan Lonowski - You directed me to the "cookie" solution and now I have it working correctly. Thank You! 
http://www.perlscriptsjavascripts.com/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 0):

Once window is unloaded all your JavaScript variables are lost, let's say you move from page 1 to page 2.

Same in the case of location.reload() happened;

MDN Doc said this:-

> The Location.reload()method Reloads the resource from the current URL.
>   Its optional unique parameter is a Boolean, which, when it is true,
>   causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is false
>   or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its cache.

Still if it is loading from cache it will load the DOM again (lose of window).

PS:-In Any case DOM will regenerate.

Answer (score 0):

[Jonathan Lonowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15031/jonathan-lonowski) directed me in the right direction to use cookies. I now have everything working correctly. I found this resource online as well: http://www.perlscriptsjavascripts.com/js/cookies.html